# Alternate ways to display forms inside a Grid row in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

The WPF application I've created contains a Grid with 3 rows. I have a set of buttons in the 3rd row. On Clicking the Buttons, the forms are displayed in the 2nd row of the Grid. However What I've done is quite messy because I've created all the form contents in the same window and have set the visibility to Hidden.

sample code:

```
<Grid Name="panel1" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Hidden">
 //contains a lot of textblocks,buttons and images
</Grid>
<Grid Name="panel2" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Hidden">
 //contains a lot of textblocks,buttons and images
</Grid>
 <Grid Name="panel3" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Hidden">
 //contains a lot of textblocks,buttons and images
</Grid>
```

My xaml Code looks like this:

```
private void Image_MouseLeftButtonDown_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        panel2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        panel3.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    }
```

This approach looks really messy as I've included all the code in the Main Xaml file.
Need some alternate ways to do this. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method like this

```
private void VisibilityManager(Grid grd)
{
    new List<Grid>(){ panel1, panel2, panel3}
       .ForEach(x => x.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden);
    grd.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

and call it like this

```
VisibilityManager(panel1);
```

for making panel1 visible and all other hidden.

In future if you have to increase your grids just make changes inside this method.

Comment: I don't have problem with the visibility setting. I need to know if I can place the panel1,panel2 and panel3 contents in a separate page(because there are a lot of contents-these panels are actually Forms) and display them on button clicks.

Comment: Can I create different  pages for each panel(panel1 as a separate page) and display them on button clicks?

Comment: You should read about `UserControls` here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol.aspx

Comment: Thank You. I've now replaced it with user controls and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You could style a tabcontrol and switch the tab, you could use a contentcontrol and create a binding to the content you want to show. You could also use a databinding (depends on what you want to display) and use a template selector... there are many ways to solve that problem. Just tell a bit more what your contents look like

Comment: Each panel(panel1,panel2 and panel3) looks like a form. So all the form contents go inside  <Grid Name="panel3" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Hidden">
 //contains a lot of textblocks,buttons and images
</Grid>